# Я не могу отправить запрос POST

Tags: python, python-3.x, requests, bs4

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


def CrackHash(HashKey):
    page = requests.get("http://www.md5decryption.com") # Получаем содержимое сайта
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, "html.parser")
    for tag in soup.findAll("input"):
        for sub in soup.findAll("input"):
            if tag["name"] == 'hash':
                if sub["name"] == 'submit':     
                    http = requests.post("http://www.md5decryption.com",data={tag['name']:HashKey, sub["name"]:'submit'})   
                    for info in soup.findAll('b'):
                        try:print(info)
                        except:pass 

a = '45af13298a22119fa84debdfc6b2d909'
CrackHash(a)
```

Программа не выдает не каких ошибок но вот тэг  с расшифрованным словом он тоже не выводит

Подскажите что делать или Где я допустил ошибку

Comment: Зачем два цикла с `soup.findAll("input")`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Код отправки POST-запроса в вопросе был очень усложнен, можно проще:

```
import re
import requests


def md5decryption(hash_: str) -> str:
    form_data = {'hash': hash_, 'submit': 'Decrypt It!'}
    rs = requests.post('http://www.md5decryption.com/', data=form_data)

    match = re.search('Decrypted Text:(.+)', rs.text)
    return match.group(1)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(md5decryption('45af13298a22119fa84debdfc6b2d909'))
    print(md5decryption('ed076287532e86365e841e92bfc50d8c'))
```

Консоль:

```
 </b>kombat</font><br/><center><script type='text/javascript'><!--
 </b>Hello World!</font><br/><center><script type='text/javascript'><!--
```

---

Как видно в консоли я не делал вытаскивание результата разбора ("kombat" и "Hello World!"), т.к. это не относится к ответу. Но, если интересно, [то тут это есть](https://github.com/gil9red/SimplePyScripts/blob/4b87e64829f337d43d27830138b90f5059e89f2e/www_md5decryption_com__online.py).

Comment: Спасибо Большое !!!!

Comment: У меня вопрос возник в программирование на питоне я скажем так любитель и вот я не понял данную строку `return match.group(1)` можете объяснить ?!

Comment: Круглые скобки в регулярных выражениях -- это группы, вот я и вернул из функции значение из первой группы. Например, нулевая группа это все выражение из регулярки (для примера: `"Decrypted Text: </b>kombat</font><br/><center><script type='text/javascript'><!--"`). Можно указывать несколько групп, а после к ним обращаться, например у `re.match('(\d)(\w)', '1d')` group(0) -- '1d', group(1) -- '1' и group(2) -- 'd'

Comment: Все понял Спасибо